# Class templates with multiple unrelated arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a class template, that creates a class with two members:

```
template<typename coordinateType, typename ...DataTypes>
class Object{

    public:

        std::tuple<coordinateType, coordinateType, coordinateType> position;


        std::tuple<std::vector<DataTypes>...> plantData;

        

};
```

The issue is, rather than calling

```
auto myObject = Object<float, int, int, int>();
```

for an instance of Object with 3 ints of data, I want to clean this up and use two separate templates, without the unrelated "float" as the first argument.

Is there a way to implement this class so that it would be the equivalent of:

```
auto myObject = Object<float>();

myObject.track<int, int, int>();
```

And if not, is it possible to separate those two template arguments in any way, or am I stuck with grouping them together?

Comment: you can defer it and make `track` to determine the type. (with some modification on call side)

Comment: What is `track` supposed to be and do? There is no function in your initial example.

Comment: the problem with your current approach is what's the type of `Object<float>().track<int>().track<int,int>()`

Comment: @Kevin What goes to plantData then? (What is it's type for `Object<float>`?)

Comment: @lorro plantData would have type ```std::tuple<>``` unless .track() is called. The only purpose that .track() serves is to defer the creation of plantData until some point in the future. It's a hypothetical. If there's a different way to do it, I'm more than open to suggestions.

Comment: @appleapple Deferring the creation of plantData is exactly what I want to do. Do you have a link to an example and/or could you explain how that would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the caller side a little, you can make `track` to return a new class.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename...Us>
struct Object{
    std::tuple<T, T, T> position;
    std::tuple<std::vector<Us>...> plantData;
};

// you can also give it a different name, here I use a specialization instead
template<typename T>
struct Object<T>{
    template<typename...Us>
    Object<T,Us...> track();
};

void foo(){
    auto myObjectCreator = Object<float>();
    auto myObject = myObjectCreator.track<int, int, int>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qhPrEaa96

Comment: And with this, I have to reassign it to an object, I can't just say ```myObjectCreator.track<int, int, int>();```, I need to assign it to ```myObject```. If so, that's fine, just wanted to make sure. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kevin yes, you because types in `c++` cannot change

Comment: @Kevin to be complete, it can to a certain point, it's called type-erasure like `std::any` and `std::variant`, but it's not like to be useful here anyway. (and the static type still not change)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like `track<Ts>` to append `Ts` to the list of `DataTypes`. This can be achieved like:

```
template<typename coordinateType, typename ...DataTypes>
class Object{

    public:
        template<typename... Ts>
        Object<coordinateType, ...DataTypes, Ts>
        track() { return {}; } // you might add proper ctor call, element copy via tuple::cat, etc.

        std::tuple<coordinateType, coordinateType, coordinateType> position;


        std::tuple<std::vector<DataTypes>...> plantData;

        

};
```